# why do I get an Error in folium.GeoJson style_funtion?

Tags: python, geojson, folium, index-error

I would like to plot coordinates with folium and fill the circles according the column "type".

I tried to do this according the example given here: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/geojson/geojson_marker.html

Somehow it doesn't work for my code:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
import folium


d = {'type': [1, 2], 'geometry': [Point(9.59, 49.29), Point(9.65, 49.35)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d, crs="EPSG:4326")

colors = ["yellow", "red"]

m = folium.Map(location=[51, 10], zoom_start=7, tiles="cartodb voyager")


folium.GeoJson(
    gdf,
    marker=folium.Circle(radius=10, fill_color="orange", fill_opacity=0.4, color="black", weight=1),
    style_function=lambda x: {
        "fillColor": colors[x['properties']['type']],
    }
).add_to(m)

m
```

I always get: **IndexError: list index out of range**

Can you please explain why this error occurs? Also I don't really understand what exactly happens in the style_function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you define only two colors (*zero-based*). So, `colors[2]` (*for type 2*) is triggering the [`IndexError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError). You can fix it this way :

```
    style_function=lambda x: {
        "fillColor": colors[x["properties"]["type"]-1], # substract 1
    }
```

Note that you can also [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the colors to the type of each location and then [`explore`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore.html) your data while passing the `type` as the color parameter :

```
( # you can store a folium.Map with `m = (`
    gdf.assign(type=gdf["type"].map(
        dict(enumerate(colors, start=1))).fillna("orange"))
       .explore(
           tiles="cartodb voyager",
           color="type",
           style_kwds={
               "radius": 4,
               "stroke": True,
               "color": "black",
               "weight": 1,
               "fillOpacity": 1,
           },
           zoom_start=12,
           width=700, height=300,
       )
)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: It seems like color="type" only works if style_kwds is also defined. If I delete style_kwds then color="type" doesn't work anymore. I think this is quiet strange. Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: *"doesn't work anymore."* means nothing. When I remove `style_kwds` in `explore`, the markers got *fill-colored* [with red and yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr4mK.jpg), so I don't understand your comment. And why do you even want to remove this parameter ? Anyways, you can't remove it and at the same time complain about the styles (edge, radius, ...) being gone..

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my mistake. When I removed `style_kwds` it seemed like the points weren't also filled with red and yellow anymore like specified in `color="type"`. But this is not true. They are still filled like specified but since radius was deleted the points were smaller and the stroke with its blue color to dominant to see the fill color. So both points looked blue and I was confused why.